# How to add custom field in registration form and add jquery validation in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, jquery, validation, registration, custom-field

How to add custom field in registration form and save in database and add jquery validation in Magento2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please check the below given answers https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/272438/52244 if it match your expectation please mark as valid answer.so if someone else got some concern they can use this valid answer. more help will be appreciated.

Comment: how are you, please find the below answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/272438/52244 if it's match your expectation then mark it as valid answers so others can use in future if they come to here, without spending much to find answer. hope you got my concern. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Add your input field

```
            <div class="field required">
                <label for="username" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Username') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
                           maxlength="50"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                           echo __('Username') ?>"
                           class="input-text"
                           data-validate="{'maxlength':50, required:true, 'validateUsername':true}">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Step 2: Add jQuery validation in the template.

```
<script>
    requirejs([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/mage',
    ], function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validateUsername',
            function (value) {
                return value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_@.]+$/);
            },
            $.mage.__('Enter a valid username. Valid characters are A-Z a-z 0-9 . _ - @.')
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a custom field in customer registration page

first if need then create a custom module [follow this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

then need to create a file `COMPANY\CUSTOMMODULE\Setup\InstallData.php` to creating custom field

```
<?php

namespace COMPANY\CUSTOMMODULE\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $eavConfig;

    private $attributeResource;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customField = "custom_field";
        $customFieldLabel = "Custom Field 1";
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $customField);

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $customField, [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => $customFieldLabel,
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $customField);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

        /*
        //You can use this attribute in the following forms
        adminhtml_checkout
        adminhtml_customer // for admin page under customer edit account info
        adminhtml_customer_address
        customer_account_create // for store-front registration page
        customer_account_edit // for store-front after logged-in account edit page
        customer_address_edit
        customer_register_address
        */

        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
}
```

**wait** it will help to just create on DB level and visible in admin-level,

Need to access same custom field in store-front

so create a layout file `COMPANY\CUSTOMMODULE\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer"
                   template="COMPANY_CUSTOMMODULE::additional.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and to display field in store-front in registration page, 
create a phtml file `COMPANY\CUSTOMMODULE\view\frontend\templates\additional.phtml`

```
<?php
$customFieldLabel = __("Custom Field 1");
$customField = "custom_field";
?>
<div class="field <?= $customField ?> required">
    <label class="label" for="<?= $customField ?>">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($customFieldLabel) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="<?= $customField ?>" id="<?= $customField ?>" value=""
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($customFieldLabel) ?>"
               class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

after added these files or code

run below **commands** :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` (for developer mode add -f to command)

```
php bin/magento cache:clear
```

**For JS validation** : In above phtml file (`COMPANY\CUSTOMMODULE\view\frontend\templates\additional.phtml`), if you need to add custom validation then use **Magento Validation classes** to **data-validate attribute**.

More help for JS validation follow this [link](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/)

**Note :  `COMPANY\CUSTOMMODULE` is the custom module, if you need you can change with your custom module.**

Hope this will help you.